# Extract the string within the angle brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this "<RC_EMAIL:someone@gmail.com> some other content…". I want to extract only the "someone@gmail.com" and display it in frontend. The string can contain any number of templates like this. I'm not able to use replaceAll("<RC_EMAIL:", ""), since it is give me result as "'someone@gmail.com>'. Can we do this with regex? or just with replaceAll method?

Comment: Yes, please see: https://javascript.info/regular-expressions

Comment: `console.log("<RC_EMAIL:someone@gmail.com> some other content…".split('>')[0].split(':')[1]);` --> please see if this helps. And, share your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let email = "<RC_EMAIL:someone@gmail.com> some other content…".replace(/<\w+:([^>]+?)>/g,"$1");
```